# reducer method not called with useDispatch in react

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have created a new component in react

```
import React, {FC, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchExternalLinks } from '../../redux/reducers/appReducer'
import { getExternalLinksSelector } from '../../redux/selectors/appSelector'

type LinksType = {
    title?: string | undefined
}

const ExternalLinks : FC<LinksType> = (props) => {
    const {
        title
    } = props
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const links = useSelector(getExternalLinksSelector)


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect')
        dispatch(fetchExternalLinks)
    })

    const openWindow = (path: string) => {
        window.open(path, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
    }

    return (
        <>
        Links:
            {links.map((link) => {
              return <a onClick={() => openWindow(link.path)}>{link.title}</a> 
            })
            }
        </>
    )
}
export default ExternalLinks
```

when I try to call the fetchExternalLinks method from reducer with dispatch, it doesn't work.

In my console I can see only "use effect", but nothing from reducer

```
export const fetchExternalLinks = (): ThunkType => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("test")
  try {
    dispatch(appActions.toggleIsFetching(true))
    const response = await appApi.getCustomers()
    dispatch(appActions.setExternalLinks(response.data))

} catch (e) {
    dispatch(appActions.toggleResponseMessage({isShown: true, isSuccess: false}))
} finally {
    dispatch(appActions.toggleIsFetching(false))
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from this,

```
dispatch(fetchExternalLinks)
```

to this,

```
dispatch(fetchExternalLinks())
```

Since you are only passing the reference, your async thunk is not getting executed, when the fetchExternalLinks function will be called using () rather than passing a reference you will receive an arrow function as a return value, to which react-redux will pass the dispatch function and will execute it for you